# Remove SAMLResponse parameter from SSO url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, adfs

I'm building Spring app which uses ADFS and SAML 2.0 for users authentication.
Problem is my ADFS doesn't want SAMLRequest parameter in the URL, but Spring adds it automatically in the end. I want to remove it.

I have SSO URL defined in application.yml like this:

```
server:
 port: 8080
 ssl:
  key-store: classpath:key.pfx
  key-store-password: somepassword
  enabled: true

spring:
 security:
   saml2:
    relyingparty:
     registration:
      adfs:
       assertingparty:
        entity-id: https://somehostname.com/
        verification:
         credentials:
          certificate-location: classpath:certificate.cer
        singlesignon:
         url: https://somehostname.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx?loginToRp=myapp&RequestedAuthentificationContext=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password
         sign-request: false
```

My expectation is to see this specific URL in browser and see FS login form when I go to `localhost:8080`, but Spring adds additional parameter &SAMLRequest=... to the end of URL:

```
https://somehostname.com/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx?loginToRp=myapp&RequestedAuthentificationContext=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password&SAMLRequest=....
```

And because of that I'm not able to see the form. I have "An error occurred" message. ADFS doesn't expect this parameter and looks like can't handle it.

How do I adjust configuration so that I wouldn't have SAMLResponse parameter in the request query?

The only thing on my mind is to manually intercept httpRequest with `doFilter` or something and manually edit request query parameters by constructing new set or parameters without SAMLResponse, but I have a feeling there must be something that allows to make this much easier.